If $B$ is PD in null space of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ then exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $B+rA^TA$ is PD

If a symmetric matrix $B$ is PD in null space of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with
rank$A=m<n$, then exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $B+rA^TA$ is PD.

What I've tried is the following: If $x\in {\cal N}(A)$, we have this being trivially satisfied. If $x \in \text{Im}(A^T)$ with $||x||=1$, it is possible to verify $-\lambda_{min}/\sigma_1²\geq -x^TBx/||Ax||²$, when $\lambda_{min}\geq0$, or $-\lambda_{min}/\sigma_r²\geq -x^TBx/||Ax||²$, when $\lambda_{min}<0$. So in either case we can take $r$ greater than this and the condition will be satisfied. The problem is the general case $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I tried using ortogonal decomposition but it didn't work so far.

what's the source of this problem and what else do you know about characterizing PD matrices?

@user8675309 The source from this problem is from a book called Elements of Non Linear Programming by Ana Friedlander. $A$ is PD in ${\cal N}(A)$ iff $z^TAz>0$ for all $z \neq 0 \in {\cal N}(A)$.

The book sounds fine, but I asked what else you know about characterizing PD matrices and you responded with a definition.  I have in mind things like Congruence and Sylvester's criterion.

@user8675309 Ah ok, I know it is equivalent to Cholesky decompostion, and all positive eigenvalues. I don't know the other 2 properties you mentioned, if you know how to solve with them go ahead.

@user8675309 I just saw what Sylvester criterion is, but I think it is a bit complicated to apply here.

I will try cholesky

$C:= A^TA \succeq \mathbf 0$ where $\text{rank } C =m$ and $\dim \ker C = d$
$\mathbf {V}  :=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} \mathbf v_1  & \mathbf v_2 &\cdots & \mathbf v_d\end{array}\bigg]$
provide a basis for $\ker C$
Your positive definiteness criterion means $P:= V^T BV  \succ\mathbf 0$ hence $d=\text{rank } V^TBV \leq \text{rank } V^TB\leq d\implies \dim \ker V^T B =n-d = m$.  Now use this to construct
$\mathbf {B}  :=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} \mathbf b_1  & \mathbf b_2 &\cdots & \mathbf b_m & V\end{array}\bigg]$
where the $\mathbf b_k $ form a basis for $\text{ker } V^T B$.  We know $\det\big (\mathbf B\big) \neq 0$ (why?).
$\mathbf B^T \big(B +r\cdot C\big)\mathbf B = \left[\begin{matrix} B_{m} & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & P\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}r \cdot C_m & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\end{matrix}\right]$
where $C_m\succ \mathbf 0\implies B_m + r\cdot C_m \succ \mathbf 0$ for $r\geq R$ large enough (why?) and $P\succ \mathbf 0$.  Thus the above matrix is PD for $r$ large enough and your original matrix is as well.  This is a special case of Sylvester's Law of Inertia but you may just verify for any $\mathbf y \in \mathbb R^n-\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$ $\implies \mathbf {Bx}= \mathbf y $ for exactly one $\mathbf x$
$\implies \mathbf y^T\big(B +r\cdot C\big)\mathbf y= \mathbf x^T\mathbf B^T \big(B +r\cdot C\big)\mathbf B\mathbf x\gt 0$

Could you detail a bit more why $\text{rank}(V^TBV) \leq \text{rank} V^TB \leq d$. I also didn't follow why the $\bf{B}$ have non zero determinant.

rank is sub-multiplicative so we always have $\text{rank }(V^TBV) \leq \text{rank } (V^TB) \leq \text{rank } V^T $  and because row rank equals column rank you know $\text{rank } V^T=\text{rank } V = d$.  As for $\det\big(\mathbf B\big)\neq 0$, I want you to first think through and tell me what vectors can possibly be in $(\ker C) \cap (\ker V^T B)$. [Hint: start by first considering a single $\mathbf v_k$ then work towards linear combinations of $\mathbf v_k$.]
